# Would every verb with be- become transitive?

Tags: verb

We know, that by adding be-, we can make intransitive verbs transitive. Can we conclude, that all be- verbs are transitive?

Comment: Does "betragen" as in "der Schaden des Gewitters beträgt 120000 Euro" count?

Comment: @0x6d64 That’s an accusative object, so no, it’s not a counterexample. (»Der Schaden beträgt einen symbolischen Euro.«)

Comment: @Jan: Danke, das hätte mir eigentlich auch auffallen sollen :)

Comment: The verbs begegnen and bestehen are often (although not exclusively) used without an accusative object. Does that count?

Comment: @Tim Yes, *begegnen* does; it never takes an accusative object as far as Wiktionary knows. See my answer.

Comment: I'm a bit in doubt, but what about "helfen" --> "behelfen"? I am not even sure that can be used in any other way than reflexively. Same with "danken", I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. In general, you can assume that every word that you create using this word formation rule will result in a transitive verb. After all, that's what it is good for. However, you can *never* safely assume that *every* word that has the structure of a certain word formation rule will *always* have the function / meaning which is common for that rule. Some words may lose their original meaning over time, or be remnants from a time when the formation rule worked differently; however, I do not know if there is an example for *be-*.

Comment: e.g. *befinden* does not follow the pattern and has a completely different meaning from *finden*.

Answer (score 5):

Transitive verbs, in the definition used by [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Valenz/Trans-Intrans.html), are those that take an accussative object, and thus those which, when transformed into the passive voice, retain a subject in the passive voice.

[**Begegnen**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/begegnen) fulfills neither condition. *Jemande**m** begegnen* uses a dative object as does *etwas begegnen*. A passive voice is only really possible for the second one:

> Dem Vorwurf wird begegnet.

You see no subject in there, thus the verb is intransitive.

Comment: folgen and begegnen are treated as exceptions in some books though.

Comment: @user1917231 Well, if they are exceptions they break the rule, mathematically speaking.

Comment: Well therefore the general rule may still apply. As a general rule of thumb, all untrennbare Verben make the stem verb transitive.

Answer (score 1):

"Bedürfen" is not transitive since it takes a genitive object: "Ich bedarf deines Rates".  No other option even in colloquial speech except for switching to some other verb like "benötigen".